# flyway - Repeatable scripts not repeated

Tags: java, sql, maven, flyway

I have recently moved from an old database migration provider to flyway (4.1.2). In our setup we have - as usual - some incremental scripts and scripts that are repeatable. So far things have worked well and I was able to recreate most of the behavior we had before with some improvements thanks to flyway. However I am experiencing weird behavior with repeatable scripts.

Lets imagine the following scripts:

```
DELETE FROM CONFIGURATION;
INSERT INTO CONFIGURATION (KEY, VALUE) VALUES ('SAF_DELAY', '22');
```

it gets executed when created and does what it is supposed to. Also an entry in schema_version is created with the checksum. Now I change the `22`to `23`and run flyway:migrate again, the script is executed and creates a **second** entry in schema_version with the new checksum. A while later I realize that the `23` is actually bad and `22` was right from the beginning so I change it back.

Now flyway refuses to execute the script again telling me that everything is up to date even though the script has changed from its previous state. I am assuming it does so because it can still find the old entry in the schema_version.

Obviously that is undesired behavior for a repeatable script, the decision point should only be the last executed checksum and not any checksum that ever executed of the script. This is also what I assume the documentation means by "Instead they are (re-)applied **every time their checksum changes**." I was looking through the configuration section of the maven plugin but could not find anything that seemed like a solution.

Since this is kind of a deal breaker for me I would be happy if you could hint me to the right direction.

Comment: I'd agree with your expectation regarding application of a repeatable migration when only it's latest checksum has changed. I'd say raise a bug / feature request for that.

Comment: I'd encourage you to stick with Flyway. I've been using it for about 3 years and managing about 15 databases - always been able to work around unique use cases and *never* had Flyway fail. As above, I reckon this would get traction as a feature / bug, but in the mean time you have options to work around this. Consider using [callbacks](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/callbacks) or a [custom checksum provider](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/api/migration/MigrationChecksumProvider) as a way to manage "data" evolution while you wait for a fix.